# Altering display on PHP page from SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, date

I have an SQL query that goes through a search and displays hundred of records for several columns.  However the display for two columns must be change; the Effective Date and the Purge Date.  Currently they are both being displayed like this: (e.g. Aug 29 1991).  I want to change the output to 29-Aug-1991.  I'm not sure how I would do this since it's pulling this data straight from the database into the table.
Please note I'm using MS-SQL and PHP for this project.

This is my SQL Query:

```
   $sql = "select SerialNum as [Serial Number],ts_sitename As Site,(case m.Scratched
   when 0 then 'Live'
   when 1 then 'Free'
   END) as Status,  Note as Comment, (case Destroyed when 0 then 'NO'
   when 1 then 'YES' END) as [Destroyed], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(mg_effectivedate as char), 1, 12) AS [Effective Date],  
   SUBSTRING(cast(mg_effectivedate as char), 12, 8) AS [Effective Time], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 1, 4) + '-' +
   SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 3, 2) + '-' +
   SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 5, 2)
   AS [Scratched Date], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 10, 2) + ':' +
   SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 12, 2) + ':' +
   SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 14, 2) 
   AS [Scratched Time], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(mg_scratchdate as char), 1, 12) AS [Purge Date], 
   (select fl_filename from TheFiles_tab where mg_filenum = fl_filenum) as [Dataset],
   (select hs_hostname from TheHosts_tab where mg_hostnum = hs_hostnum) as [Host], 
   (select UserCode from [User] where mg_usernum = UserId) as [UserCode]
   from ((Media m left join MediaGenT g on m.MediaId = g.mg_medianum) 
   join TheSites_tab s on m.SiteId = s.ts_sitenum) 
   join Note n on m.NoteId = n.NoteId
   where SerialNum like '" . $userQuery . "%'";
```

And this my code to display the two columns:

```
   echo '<th>Effective Date</th>';
   echo '<th>Purge Date</th>';

   foreach ($result as $r) 
   { 
   echo "<tr>"; 
   echo "<td>".$r['Serial Number'] . " </td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$r['Site'] . " </td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$r['Status'] . "</td> ";
   echo "<td>".$r['Comment'] . " </td>";  
   echo "<td>".$r['Destroyed'] . " </td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$r['Effective Date'] . " </td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$r['Effective Time'] . "</td> ";

   echo "<td>"; 
   if ($r['Scratched Date'] == "") { 
   echo "NULL"; 
   } 
   else { 
   echo $r['Scratched Date']; 
   }  echo "</td>";

   echo "<td>" ;
   if ($r['Scratched Time'] == "") { 
   echo "NULL"; 
   } 
   else { 
   echo $r['Scratched Time']; 
   }  echo "</td>";


   echo "<td>".$r['Purge Date'] . " </td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$r['Dataset'] . "</td> ";
   echo "<td>".$r['Host'] . " </td>";  
   echo "<td>".$r['UserCode'] . " </td>";  
   echo "<td>".$r['NoteId'] . " </td>"; 
   echo "</tr>";
   }
```

Please note that I'm new to the SO community.  I've always used this website in research but have just created an account for the very first time.

Comment: You could use something like `list($month, $day, $year) = explode($r['Effective Date']);` then just `echo("$day-$month-$year");`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @technoh would that change the display for all the records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you simply want to substitute the spaces in the dates for hyphens?

Right now your dates are of the format:
`MMM DD YYYY`

You want this:
`DD-MMM-YYYY`

If I remember correctly, in PHP, you can do this:

```
$effective_date = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($r['Effective Date']));
```

That converts the database-pulled value to a timestamp, and then formats that timestamp into a new date notation. Look up php's date() function for what other options you have: [PHP: date - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Same goes for the other date(s) you want to change.

**EDIT**

Total PHP code:

```
echo '<th>Effective Date</th>';
echo '<th>Purge Date</th>';

foreach ($result as $r) 
{
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>".$r['Serial Number'] . " </td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$r['Site'] . " </td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$r['Status'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td>".$r['Comment'] . " </td>";  
    echo "<td>".$r['Destroyed'] . " </td>";
    echo "<td>".date("d-M-Y", strtotime($r['Effective Date'])) . " </td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$r['Effective Time'] . "</td> ";

    echo "<td>"; 
    if ($r['Scratched Date'] == "") { 
    echo "NULL"; 
    } 
    else { 
    echo $r['Scratched Date']; 
    }  echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>" ;
    if ($r['Scratched Time'] == "") { 
    echo "NULL"; 
    } 
    else { 
    echo $r['Scratched Time']; 
    }  echo "</td>";


    echo "<td>".date("d-M-Y", strtotime($r['Purge Date'])) . " </td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$r['Dataset'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td>".$r['Host'] . " </td>";  
    echo "<td>".$r['UserCode'] . " </td>";  
    echo "<td>".$r['NoteId'] . " </td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: so where would I add that line of code in my file? Would I replace one of the td or th tags with it?

Comment: Allow me to edit my post, I'll post the complete PHP code for you, 1 sec.

Comment: this is working perfectly, thank you floris.

Comment: No problem. It was almost too easy, you could probably have figured this out with some googling but I'm not one to deny someone help :)